# Error Message "Cron not running", but it's working perfectly. CiviCRM 5.43.0

Tags: wordpress, cron, cron-job, scheduled-job

I've seen a couple of Drupal workarounds for this, but not for Wordpress.

The CiviCRM status is below; note that the last reported cron run was manually executed by me.

> All extensions are up-to-date:
> CKEditor4: Version 5.43.0
> Contribution cancel actions: Version 5.43.0
> Event Cart: Version 5.43.0
> Financial ACLs: Version 5.43.0
> Theme: Greenwich: Version 5.43.0
> Custom search framework: Version 5.43.0
> reCAPTCHA: Version 5.43.0
> Sequential credit notes: Version 5.43.0

> PHP Up-to-Date
> This system uses PHP version 7.4.26 which meets or exceeds the recommendation of 7.3.

> Cron Not Running
> Last cron run at November 26th, 2021 2:35 PM.

I have a separate Cron task for each Scheduled Job, specified on cPanel using the CLI method (because this works better than wget, and no other method worked for me). I can see all tasks are running as they should [Administer > System Settings > Scheduled Jobs], yet the "Cron Not Running" message still pops-up constantly too. This is really annoying.

Here's an example of one of my cPanel Cron jobs, working as expected at 1AM daily (0 1 * * *)

`/usr/local/bin/ea-php74 /home/ACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php -s MYDOMAIN -j -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD -e job -a version_check >/dev/null 2>&1`

So what triggers this Cron error message? I have set job=version_check to run only once a day, yet it suggests more frequently - "CiviCRM Update Check (Always)". How can you "always" run a periodic job? Is that relevant? Is this just a dumb bug?

Answer (score 1):

It's hardcoded that it needs to be hourly or more: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/69cd824e26fc6e90a88e6cf18d9d011c1c85b94e/CRM/Utils/Check/Component/Env.php#L317

And I'm pretty sure it's tracking the Job.execute job, not any individual job: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/69cd824e26fc6e90a88e6cf18d9d011c1c85b94e/CRM/Core/JobManager.php#L72

Comment: Yes, I get the same thing on any of my sites where we're not running the cron every hour (or more). A lot of ours are set to like every 3 hours or so, so we always have this error come up. I just told it to hide it or whatever so it wouldn't bug me.

Comment: I increased the frequency of version_check to every hour, but the message still appears. Clearly in my situation, only a manual job execution will satisfy the criteria to make this go away (and then only for an hour).  The last thing I want to do is start hacking into core functions when my PHP skills are basic.

Comment: Is there a reason you need separate cron jobs instead of running job.execute? I.e. just have one cron job with `-a execute` and enable the jobs at Admin - System Settings - Scheduled Jobs. You could still have individual jobs run separately in addition if you really want.

Comment: Aha.  I didn't fully understand the baffling cron documentation.  So the solution appears to be; 

1. at Admin - System Settings - Scheduled Jobs, enable only jobs that don't require parameters (e.g. version_check, cleanup) and let job.execute manage their execution

2. trigger jobs that require parameters separately

I didn't realise (until I just tried it) that you can trigger jobs without them being enabled at Admin - System Settings - Scheduled Jobs. That's not mentioned anywhere.

Thanks for your help! Problem solved.

Comment: Yes civi cron can be difficult to get going, especially the first time.